# What does the MPU6050s DMP initialization data mean?

Tags: embedded, mpu6050, dmp

I was wondering what are those [3kB of hex data](https://github.com/sparkfun/9DOF_Razor_IMU/blob/51dbea98591c547e73c2511f2339e35e4bd7ad48/Libraries/Arduino/src/util/inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.c#L223) loaded to DMP on initialization. I know they are supposed to be some kind of “program” for DMP, but what do they do? Is there a way to get assembly version, and if so, is there a way to make my own? Or, am I misunderstanding this completely? Everyone just seems to be using this but I couldn't find any documentation regarding this data.

Comment: Essentially this is a "where's the documentation?" question, so off topic. It seems that InvenSense have been restrictive with their IP, and now the part is obsolete. To get any information you need to log on to their developer forum, but I found [this](https://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/153-official-dmp-documentation-is-released-by-invensense/) which may be what you need. The link in the post goes to the Dev forum, and I chose not to sign up - your task

Comment: @Clifford I guess that is what this question is... But, the problem is, I already found and read the documentation(at least all that I could find, yes even the one behind registration). But it just says "Upload this magic 3kB of data into DMP." And while it provides some functions that change the behaviour (e.g. enable some features), it doesn't explain what the "firmware code", as they call it, actually does... (well it does the calculations, obviously, but how?) So I think my question is still relevant...

Comment: By all accounts it performs the sensor fusion; possibly by Kalman filter. But in the end the vendor has chosen to assert their intellectual property rights and not publish their corporate secrets. That' s fair enough; it's their invention.